# jQuery DataTables's on() events listener with multiple events

Tags: javascript, datatables

Since I have similar actions for selecting a row on a DataTable, I want to use [on()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/on()) function from its API (not from jQuery). Even it is mentioned that I can separate multiple event names with a space, it actually just gets the last written one. See [this example](https://codepen.io/barisoztop/pen/grKxNq) where I added a "select deselect" events to listen:

`t.on( "select deselect", function( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        console.log( "select deselect" );
    } );`

Any idea?

Comment: It's a bug https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the namespaced event names seems to fix it

Change to

```
t.on( "select.dt deselect.dt" ...
```

Comment: For the reason why this works, see the bug linked to by @andrey-etumyan - I only discovered it by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this specific scenario could be to apply multiple events **1 by 1** in a loop

```
var eventNames = ['select', 'deselect'];

for(i=0;i<eventNames.length;i++)
{
    t.on(eventNames[i], function( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        console.log(e); // it will tell you the event
        // you can also do more according to the event like
        //doSomeThing(e,indexes);
    });
}
```